# Nicaragua visa letter

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, visas-on-arrival, us-residents, nicaragua

I am planning to travel to Nicaragua in November, The consulate needs me to provide a visa interview letter with the purpose of visit and other details. Does anyone have a sample format for this letter, For some reason am not able to find it online

Comment: I am from India and live in US on H1B visa. The purpose is tourism and will be staying there for two weeks.

Comment: I checked with the Nicaraguan embassy here and they told be to apply for a visa before travelling. I will probably check with them again. Thanks

Comment: @r7v Don't check with them, since they are **not** the ones who decide the entry requirements. The simple fact is that you **will** be able to get a visa on arrival since you have a US visa

Answer (score 8):

This is what Timatic (courtesy [KLM](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&HEALTH=1&VISA=1&NA=IN&AR=US&EM=US&DE=NI&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C)) has to say:

> National India (IN)             /Residence USA (US)
>   Embarkation USA (US)            /Destination Nicaragua (NI)

Nicaragua (NI)

Passport required. 
- Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
  valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date. 
Passport Exemptions:

- Passengers with a machine-readable (ICAO 9303 compliant)
  temporary passport.

Visa required, except for Passengers with a residence or a
re-entry permit issued by USA. 
    NOTE 43894: This does not apply to nationals of India with a normal passport. 
Visa Issuance:
Visa required, except for Holders of normal passports issued
to nationals of India can obtain a visa on arrival for a max. stay of 30 days. Fee: USD 50.-: 
 - applicable to holders of a Residence Permit issued by USA; 
Additional Information:

- Nationals of Nicaragua holding dual nationality, For details, click here
- All visitors are required to obtain a Tourist Card on
  arrival. Fee: USD 10.-:
- Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds to
  cover their stay and documents required for their next
  destination.

  -exempt are unaccompanied minors.
- Extension possible. Fee: USD 2.- per day of stay.
  Warning:
- Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry:

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: And that's why I don't link from KLM anymore. They throw the result into a frame and make it annoying to get the actual link. And those dropdowns are annoying. For a more _expert_ interface, see [here](http://www.flightworx.aero/timatic/tables.php).

Answer (score 6):

Don't listen to the embassy - if they say you cannot get a visa on arrival they're **wrong**, and possibly trying to get at your money on purpose.

Indian citizens with a US visa **can** get a visa on arrival. It says so in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=NI&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), which is a database used worldwide by airlines checking passengers, and is based on information **directly from local border authorities**.

So don't even speak to the embassy - you **can** get a visa on arrival, full stop.